# Access Oracle Database v.10 using Python/cx-Oracle?

Tags: python, django, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle DB v10.1 using Python/Django. Therefore cx_Oracle is needed. cx_Oracle (Current version, down to [v5.3](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Oracle/5.3/)) needs a minimum oracle_instantclient version of 11.2. Which is incompatible with  the OracleDB 10.x.

- So when I use client 10.2 to connect to DB 10.1, it works from the Oracle client side, but Python/cx_Oracle fails because it needs minimum client 11.2
- Using an newer Version of the client (11.2+), cx_Oracle is happy, but the client says that the server (10.2) is too old to connect.
- Even trying to install an old cx_Oracle from the Pypi archive (5.2.1) fails, because it either doesn't support Python3 (my project), or I can't even install it in a Python2.7 test environment.

```
[...]
  File "/home/<snip>/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 705, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/tmp0B1fptbuild/cx-oracle/


Is there any way to connect to an old Oracle 10.x DB from Python (maybe without cx_Oracle), or even better, from Django?
```

Comment: Did you try 11.2 client?  I have some notes saying it should connect to 9.2 or later.  A 12.2, 18 or 19 client will connect to 11.2 or later.

Comment: Yes, tried 11.2, 18, 19. Did not work. Cannot connect to this server version.